# How to get inner value inside a tag? - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have an array of tags like this:

```
const tagArray = [<Text>Text1</Text>, <Text>Text2</Text>, <Text>Text3</Text>];
```

And I want to get the inner value of them this way:

```
tagArray[0].innerValue; //Output: Text1
```

I have searched ways to do this but I didn't find a solution. On web we use `innerHTML` but obviously that do not work here, how can I do this?

Notice that I do not want to update the value, I just need the inner text.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only text (and not another HTML tags, etc.) wrapped by your custom <Text></Text> component, you can access it like this:

```
tagArray[0].props.children
```

The

```
typeof(tagArray[0].props.children)
```

is already a string in this case.